# File Uploader + XML generating script

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, file-upload

I need an admin panel, that allows us to Write content, and upload multiple images and pdf files, and I need them in xml (rss feed) so that my program can fetch it easily.

I thought about blogs, eg. wordpress. But they dont provide tags for attachments. 
Is there another free script that would do this? or is there a workaround?

What i want is the feed to have a line like `<attachement>www.mywebsite.com/post11312/file.pdf</attachment`>

Comment: Try using Google to find answers before posting questions. I literally typed in "WordPress Attachment Taxonomies" and found your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to add tags to attachments in side of WordPress there is a plugin for that called [Attachment Taxonomy Support](https://wordpress.org/plugins/attachment-taxonomy-support/).

If you want to add the [RSS `<enclosure>` tag](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification) the RSS output of a feed in WordPress good news!  **It's built in.**

On each post you want to add an enclosure or "attachment" you simply add a [custom field](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) called "enclosure" with the field value equal to the URL of the file.  This is a little known function in WordPress, I'm not surprised you didn't find a lot about it. The custom field will be found by the [rss_enclosure()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/rss_enclosure) function and outputted in your feed.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the "Taxonomy" .. Sorry!

Comment: But will that add the xml tag in the feed?

Comment: What i want is the feed to have a line like <attachement>www.mywebsite.com/post11312/file.pdf</attachment>

Comment: Ahhh... it would be best if you described you're desired output conditions in your question.  This is now a very different question.

Comment: I don't recommend deviating from the RSS 2.0 specification for no reason.  You should find a way to re-write your program so that it uses the standard RSS enclosure tag instead of one you are making up.